# Swift Compile error: file-create-write with pod that worked previously

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, macos-sonoma

I've just switched from Monterey to Sonoma, and from the internal HDD (erased) to an external. After the switchover, I'm getting a file-write-create error when trying to compile a project that hasn't been touched for about a year.

```
error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(17825) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/danieldonaldson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestComposer-fkrrttghacwdgdgvsgqetjnfbbxl/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestComposer.app/Frameworks/SwiftSVG.framework/.Info.plist.uRrjb7 (in target 'TestComposer' from project 'TestComposer')
```

I've tried deleting the Derived Data, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

I've updated the pod (now 2.3.0, was 2.0), but that seems to be another issue.

What exactly does this indicate, and does it come down to a problem with the pod's source code?

The header in the error is, "Run Custom Shell Script '[CP] Embed Pods Framework'

EDIT/ADDED INFO

I hadn't thought to check, but the git repo had uncommitted files, so that was committed. Now a different error seems to happen:

```
mkdir -p /Users/danieldonaldson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestComposer-fkrrttghacwdgdgvsgqetjnfbbxl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestComposer.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/danieldonaldson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestComposer-fkrrttghacwdgdgvsgqetjnfbbxl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftSVG/SwiftSVG.framework" "/Users/danieldonaldson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestComposer-fkrrttghacwdgdgvsgqetjnfbbxl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestComposer.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
SwiftSVG.framework/Info.plist
SwiftSVG.framework/SwiftSVG
SwiftSVG.framework/_CodeSignature/
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/Users/danieldonaldson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestComposer-fkrrttghacwdgdgvsgqetjnfbbxl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestComposer.app/Frameworks/SwiftSVG.framework/_CodeSignature" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
*** Skipping everything below this failed directory ***
rsync: mkstemp "/Users/danieldonaldson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestComposer-fkrrttghacwdgdgvsgqetjnfbbxl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestComposer.app/Frameworks/SwiftSVG.framework/.Info.plist.eKMDsg" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: mkstemp "/Users/danieldonaldson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestComposer-fkrrttghacwdgdgvsgqetjnfbbxl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestComposer.app/Frameworks/SwiftSVG.framework/.SwiftSVG.H5hgfW" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

sent 826770 bytes  received 70 bytes  1653680.00 bytes/sec
total size is 830166  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/98ed8ad3-3356-11ee-9b53-aead88ae2785/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Again, it seems to be connected to access to the file system. I am unable to work out how this might be connected to the change to a different drive configuration, but it seems possible....

Answer (score 7):

The answer is in Build Settings. In Build Options, set Ueer Script Sandboxing to false....

Comment: Thank you! It's worked for me. You saved my day.

Comment: Worked for me. Specifically - "User Script Sandboxing" in Build Settings needs to be set to "no". Thanks.