# Error while archiving Xcode project: Sandbox: mkdir(23381) deny(1) file-write-create

Tags: ios, xcode, build, archive, build-error

I am currently trying to archive my xcode project and i am getting this error:

> Sandbox: mkdir(23381) deny(1) file-write-create

Does anyone know what this error means? I am not using swift or anything for my project, I am just using xcode to build it.

Comment: Related: [Swift Compile error: file-create-write with pod that worked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77272843/swift-compile-error-file-create-write-with-pod-that-worked-previously?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C60.6360).

Comment: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/solar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-exafbzcdrpuigiaqxbhhlirzwpsu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphonesimulator/il2cpp.a'

When I do that, it gives me this error